# How to get login attempts using spring security core plug in case of failure

Tags: grails, spring-security

I want know failed attempt.How many times user tried to log in.I am using this plugin `compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"`.

Is it possible to find out failed attempts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to record/track them using the events provided by the plugin. Check the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/events.html) for further information.

Specifically you will be interested in the `AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent` event or even more generically the `AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent` (as Gaurav has pointed out in the comments).

Comment: It's just one of the types of authentication failure. `AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent` seems to be a better choice

Answer (score 0):

@Joshua's answer is close but not complete as it wouldn't catch authentication failures for reasons other than "bad credentials". `AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent` seems to be the best choice. Refer to the section [Registering Callback Closures](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/events.html#registeringCallbackClosures) of the documentation...

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true

grails.plugin.springsecurity. onAbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent = {
     e, appCtx -> // handle AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent
}
```

…or you could implement `ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent>` as described in the section [Registering an Event Listener](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/events.html#registeringEventListener)